# jarsigner default signature algorithm fails

Tags: jar, digital-signature, jarsigner, jar-signing, wincrypt

The jarsigner default signature algorithms are periodically updated to stronger ones. For us, using a local certificate, this used to be SHA1withDSA. Now it's SHA256withDSA for the same certificate. SHA1withDSA is actually disabled as unsecure now.

When I verify the new JAR file with `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs xyz.jar`, the result is as expected:

```
Digest algorithm: SHA-256
Signature algorithm: SHA256withDSA, 1024-bit key (weak)
```

However, when I verify the same JAR file using openSSL with `openssl cms -cmsout -inform DER -print -in LOCALSIG.DSA`, it still reports SHA1withDSA:

```
digestAlgorithms:
    algorithm: sha256 (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1)
signature:
    algorithm: dsaWithSHA1 (1.2.840.10040.4.3)
sig_alg:
    algorithm: dsaWithSHA1 (1.2.840.10040.4.3)
```

Similar with `openssl pkcs7 -inform der -print_certs -text -in LOCALSIG.DSA`:

```
Signature Algorithm: dsaWithSHA1
```

**Question 1:** How is it possible that both tools report different signature algorithms? They used to report the same algorithms before. One of them must be wrong. Perhaps the jarsigner created an ambiguous format?

The reason why I double-checked this is that I use a custom JAR verifier, built with the Windows crypto APIs. It used to work fine for years, but can't handle this new JAR file. The first crypto API function I'm calling (`CryptVerifyDetachedMessageSignature()`) already returns a rather unhelpful and undocumented error (`50 = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED = "The request is not supported."`). I guess that's because of the ambiguous format.

**Question 2:** Is there any way to handle this weird signature in my code? Or should I rely on fixing this at the source, namely the JAR file?

Or current workaround is to explicitly specify `jarsigner -sigalg SHA1withDSA`.

I should also mention that we don't use the original Oracle jarsigner, but the one from SAPMachine, based on OpenJDK IIRC.

Comment: With the help of @dave_thompson_085 we established that the JAR file is correctly signed and the problem lies with my code or CryptVerifyDetachedMessageSignature(). I posted a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77410519/9635694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta: this part of the Q is not really programming or development but I need formatting; will delete if necessary.

> `openssl cms -cmsout -inform DER -print -in LOCALSIG.DSA` still reports SHA1withDSA:

```
digestAlgorithms:
    algorithm: sha256 (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1)
signature:
    algorithm: dsaWithSHA1 (1.2.840.10040.4.3)
sig_alg:
    algorithm: dsaWithSHA1 (1.2.840.10040.4.3)
```

You're not paying attention to headings. The first two lines are almost directly under `d.signedData:` and are for the hash used in signing the data; the latter two pairs are under

```
    certificates:
      d.certificate:
```

and they describe the signature *in the certificate*, not the signature on the data. If this is a self-signed certificate, then its signature does not affect security and can be ignored; if it is a 'real' (CA-issued) certificate you should get a new certificate from the (or any suitable) CA.

If you look further down under `signerInfos:` you should see `signatureAlgorithm:` and *that* is for the signature on the data.

> Similar with `openssl pkcs7 -inform der -print_certs -text -in LOCALSIG.DSA`

`pkcs7 -print_certs -text` displays ONLY the certificate(s), not ANY information about the data signature; in fact in spite of the name it is designed for 'p7b/p7c' format data which has *only* certificate(s) and/or CRL(s) and no data signature at all. See [my answer on a better Stack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73156/whats-the-difference-between-x-509-and-pkcs7-certificate).

As to your actual problem, it's probably the 'custom verifier' but as you give no information about it I can't even try to help (not that I can help much with MSCAPI/CNG anyway, but some people here can). FWIW you could see if OpenSSL thinks the signature is valid with -- (expanded) if the .SF file is self-contained i.e. the cert is selfsigned, or directly under a root, or the chain/intermediate cert(s) is(are) included:

```
openssl cms -in LOCALSIG.DSA -inform der -verify -content LOCALSIG.SF -CAfile ss_or_root.pem
```

If cert is under an intermediate that is omitted from the .SF -- which might occur if the keystore you used to sign is not set up 'canonically' -- it is still *possible* to fully verify but more complicated; probably better to settle for `-CAfile imed.pem -partial_chain`.

Alternatively, as you reference in comments, for this case we only need to check the data signature and not the certificate at all, so just using `-noverify` and you don't need `-CAfile` or to worry about the chain if any being complete.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, you're absolutely right about the openSSL output. Under `signerInfos`, I have `digestAlgorithm: sha256 (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1)` and `signatureAlgorithm: dsaEncryption (1.2.840.10040.4.1)`. Does that confirm that it's actually SHA256withDSA?

Comment: Regarding `openssl cms -verify ...`, I used `openssl smime -verify ...` before, which seems to give the same output. I didn't mention it, because I thought that would only verify the content, not the signature. In fact, adding `-nosigs` does not change the output. That might be due to `-noverify` being also present in order to avoid errors about the self-signed certificate. Could you please clarify your comment about verifying self-signed certs with `--`?

Comment: OK, so I just added `-CAfile localSigning.cer` to the verify command lines. The results are still the same as with `-noverify` and `-nosigs`. Kinda inconclusive...

Comment: (1) assuming you have `signedAttrs: <ABSENT>` then yes digalg=sha256 and sigalg=dsa is the old-style PKCS7 encoding for dsa-with-sha256. (2) `cms -verify` and `smime -verify` should be the same as each other, but not (at all) the same as `cms -cmsout`, is that what you meant? The default for both is to verify the data against the signature using the cert _and_ validate the cert against its chain and CA; `-nosigs` skips the first (so you don't want that) and `-noverify` skips the second (so that's okay for you; I editted to note).